# Automated JNI building

Tags: java, ant, build, makefile, java-native-interface

Is there a simple and portable way to build JNI - in particular the C components - with an automated build system such as `ant` or `make` (or both, with one calling the other) without having to manually input things like the extension of the final library file or the path to the Java includes folder to the C compiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really the case for a build environment variable.  You can default it to $(JAVA_HOME)/include and $(JAVA_HOME)/lib; I think this is I did back when I used JNI.